# Como ejecutar varios procesos mapReduce con MrJob usando yield en una misma clase

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Estoy desarrollando un análisis de sentimientos de tweets usando MapReduce y MrJob. Funciona correctamente el cálculo de sentimientos por área geográfica que quiero analizar, pero a la vez que calculo el puntaje de un área, quiero contar los tweets publicados para esas áreas. De manera resumida, las funciones son las siguientes:

Ejemplo función mapper:

```
def tweets_mapper(self, _, line):
    weights = self.Dictionary("/Data/Redondo_words.csv")
    try:
        jsonLine = json.loads(line)
        place = jsonLine["place"].get('country').encode('utf8')
        place = place.encode('utf-8')
        text = jsonLine["text"]
        score = self.tweet_Score(text, weights)
        yield (place, score)
    except:
        pass
```

Ejemplo función reducer:

```
def reducer(self, word, value):
    yield word, sum(value)
```

Ejemplo función steps:

```
def steps(self):
    return [MRStep(mapper=self.tweets_mapper,
               reducer=self.tweets_reducer_scores)
        ]
```

Con esta estructura mapreduce, ya ejecuto correctamente los puntajes por zona geográfica, si quiero contar tweets por zona geográfica sólo cambio la siguiente línea del mapper:

```
yield (place, 1)
```

El problema es que necesito a la par ambos resultados y no consigo incluirlos en una misma ejecución.

He probado a crear unas funciones mapper y reducer para los scores de sentimientos por zona geográfica y otra función mapper y reducer para contar los tweets por zona geográfica, para lo cual modifico la función steps así:

```
def steps(self):
    return [MRStep(mapper=self.tweets_mapper_scores,
               reducer=self.tweets_reducer_scores),
            MRStep(mapper=self.tweets_mapper_counts,
               reducer=self.tweets_reducer_counts)
        ]
```

Cuando ejecuto el código sólo para los scores funciona, si lo ejecuto sólo para los counts funciona, pero cuando intento realizar los dos cálculos a la vez, deja de dar resultados.

Podéis decirme como ejecutar varios procesos mapReduce con MrJob usando yield en una misma clase?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como work-around para resolver lo que buscaba (calcular el puntaje por área y contar los tweets publicados para esas áreas) y obtener la media por área. Encontré la siguiente opción con un solo mapper y un solo reducer así:

```
   def tweets_mapper(self, _, line):
        try:
            jsonLine = json.loads(line)
            place = None
            if 'lang' and 'place' and 'text' in jsonLine:
                if (jsonLine['lang'] == "en") and (jsonLine['place'] is not None):
                    place = jsonLine["place"].get('country_code')
                    if place is not None:
                        location = self.get_country_name(place, countries)
                        text = jsonLine["text"]
                        score = self.tweet_Score(text, weights)
                        yield (location, (score, 1))
        except:
            pass

    def tweets_reducer(self, location, punctuation):
        count = 0
        total_score = 0
        for score, counter in punctuation:
            count += counter
            total_score += score
        mean_score = round((total_score / count), 2)
        yield location, mean_score

    def steps(self):
        return [MRStep(mapper=self.tweets_mapper,
                       reducer=self.tweets_reducer)
                ]
```